# How to break out of a loop in project reactor?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I want to write some codes using reactor like this:

```
String callRemote(String server){
  //remote call
...
}

List<String> servers = ...
String result = null;
for(String server: servers){ 
try{
     result = callRemote(server); // should be called in sequence
     if(result.equals("success")){
        break;
     }
    }catch(TimeoutException e){ //timeout control
        //
    }

}
```

At the beginning, I think `Flux.takeWhile` will be a good choice, but it is hard to control the timeout for every `callRemote`.
And then I tried `Mono.zipWhen` and `Mono.then` , but I cant break the execution chain.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `filterWhen()`:

```
// return async first success
return Flux.just(servers).flatMap(this::connect)
        .filterWhen(result -> Mono.just(result.equalsIgnoreCase("success"));
```

Check Javadoc of `filterWhen()`

Comment: `filterWhen`  does not guarantee sequential execution. What I want is that when the first server returns OK, the second server wont be requested.

Comment: Then maybe you can check `switchOnFirst` (but I haven't used it yet)

Comment: Or `onErrorReturn`/`onErrorMap` which guanrantees the first pipeline runs first, and only when errors out, execute the second.

Comment: The reference is always a good place to find the suitable operator: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling

Comment: Also, to circuit break, check this: https://blog.trifork.com/2019/07/01/parallel-short-circuiting-with-reactive-programming/